# Mongoose : advance search query using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to make search query in which there can be max 5 parameters but it may have any number of params from below 5.

## 01.name_or_number

## 02.from_date

## 03.to_date

## 04.is_validated

## 05.is_premium

I am able to make query as below.

```
var query = {$or:[
    {'name':nameOrNumber},
    {'number': nameOrNumber}
  ]};
```

I want to make such query which should only have field that has value.

Something like if user selects from_date and to_date and other 3 fields are blank then query should search using only 2 date params.

I can make multiple queries by if/else but i want to make single query which can do this.

Case 1 :-
User can search using name_or_number

Case 2 :-
User can search using from_date and/or to_date

Case 3 :-
User can search using both name_or_number and date

Case 4 :-
User can search using is_validated and/or is_premium

Case 5 :-
User can search with all 5 params

More Cases...

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: So `$or` basically takes a "list" or "array" of arguments. It ( like the whole MongoDB Query DSL ) is actually just a plain JavaScript object or array. Just manipulate the object. Push new items onto the array as needed.

Comment: @Neil... I have started learning it few days back. Is it possible to show me by code or reference.

Comment: Learning what? JavaScript? It's basic list manipulation of which I am attempting to point you to realizing. Nothing special here, and just plain data structures.

Comment: @Neil,  I have done it as you suggested. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer given here then? There is no array manipulation demonstrated in the response for constructing an `$or` query at all. Which is what you need here. It honestly looks like the user who answered "ripped" the supplied response from another existing answer. You really should not reward people for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You will need to create a dynamically generated query object for your mongoose query (called 'queryObj' in this example). Your server side script should iterate through the data sent to the server from client side that the user has selected to search for, creating in the process key-value pairs containing a property name (e.g. 'name') to search your MongoDB collection for and a potential match/matches (e.g. 'David'). Note, I recommend storing the potential matches for each property name in an array. Finally, you simply place and use that queryObj in a mongoose find query as follows:

```
    var queryObj = {};

 // iterate through the data you sent to the server 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].values.length > 0) {
        queryObj[data[i].keys] = { $in: data[i].values };
      }
    }

// now place that new object into your mongoose query
    Account.find(queryObj, function (err, results) {
         if (err) { 
            throw err; 
         } else {
         // do whatever you want with your results
           results;
         }
    });
```

Comment: I have done it as suggested by Neil. Thanks for your efforts.